# Split row into Multiple Rows in stored procedure in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to split rows into multiple rows based on value of a column.For Example
If I have working hrs from 1 to 8 in one row I want to split it in two rows one from 1 to 4 and other from 4 to 8

```
Table is as follows-

hrs         end        name                   class
1           8          s                      3
```

I want to divide it into like

```
hrs         end        name                   class
1           4          s                      1
4           8          s                      2
```

Please reply

Comment: Please explain the logic on how "1-8" gets split into two rows.  Also, why does the `class` value change.

Comment: how can i know that i have to split it into two columns for that...

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem you should solve in sql..

Comment: if class value is 3 then we divide it into two rows one containing 1 class and other containing 2 and number of hours i.e. (1-8) also divide it into 2 parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following concept to split one row into two rows

```
select 1 as hrs, 4 as end , name, 1 as class from theTable WHERE class=3
UNION
select 4  as hrs, 8 as end, name, 2 as class from theTable WHERE class=3
```

Of course you need to parameterize the class and other values.

Comment: what if the class is 4 , u will add one more union statement?

Comment: i am not sure how do you expect the result if class=4. you may need to add additional union in that case

Comment: What if there is one more row of data?